# java.sql.sqlnontransientconnectionexception: java.net.connectException : error connecting to server localhost on port

Tags: java, jdbc, netbeans, client, derby

I've being working on a java project using Derbyclient (database locally hosted). I'm done with everything except that when I'm trying the desktop app while I'm not manually connected to the database (from Netbeans), the error in the title pops up and I can't seem to solve it. Thank you for taking the time to read this and help me.

Comment: Can you paste the full error with stack trace at the end of your question instead of just the start in the title?  There should be code that says  DriverManager.getConnection(...).  Can you also paste that code?

Comment: Here it is: http://i60.tinypic.com/33ufvrt.png

Comment: I've used this url "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Suppliers;create=true" with username and password "root". Everything works fine when netbeans is open and the conenction with the db is made.

Comment: Please fix your title to agree with the actual exception, not a mangled version of it.

Answer (score 3):

Derby can be run in two modes embedded or server-based. Server-based allows multiple programs to access the same database. Embedded allows your application to run without a server. Your url selects server-based. The connection refused error indicates that the server is not running. Since the server was started within Netbeans it is shutdown when Netbeans is not running.

The options are:

1. Switch to embedded.
2. Start the server with a command outside Netbeans.
3. Just keep Netbeans running.

To switch to embedded see Apache's documentation for deployment options:
Eliminate the "//localhost:1527" from the url.
also see the tutorial "Run SQL using the embedded driver" at https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/getstart/index.html

To start the server in a seperate command window see the syntax for derbyrun.jar:
https://builds.apache.org/job/Derby-docs/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/out/getstart/rgsderbyrunjarsyntax.html

Comment: Thank you for answer. But, I was wondering if there is anyway you can give me a quick tutorial or something to better understand. I tried the steps cited in the first link but nothing worked

Comment: That first link IS the tutorial. It's also available here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/getstart/ Please try to say something more specific than "nothing worked", or else people won't be able to help you.