# How to Distribute (Export) a Java Application project with Database?

Tags: database, connection, export, derby

I've created a Java application with a Database running on Derby 10.10.2.0 (JDK 1.7 )
The problem is when NetBeans 7.3.1 is opened and the Database is connected everything works fine .
But when I compile and build this application then go to dist folder inside NetBeans Projects , I run the application and the database won't connect .
This is the code to connect to the Database :

```
    String url = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/reflet;create=true";
    String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
    String userName = "root"; 
    String password = "admin";

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);

    conn.close();
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32020133/193453

Comment: Is there any difference in your classpath when running directly inside NetBeans versus when you try to run it externally?