# JDBC connectivity issues while connecting to data base in a network

Tags: java, jdbc

I designed a java application using net beans, which connects to a database that is present on port 1527 and retrieves data. I have prepared a executable jar file by using build and compile. After running the jar i am getting the following error.

```
     java.sql.sqlnontransientconnectionexception java.net.connectexception
 error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message connection refused connect
```

I have written the following code for connecting to derby database

```
 Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
 String host= "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/database/project.db;create=true";
               Connection conn;
               String user="user1";
               String pass="pass1";
               conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,user,pass);
               if (conn!= null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Connected to database");
            }
```

Is this error because of un availability of db on server or i have to do anything other than the code?

If i use a local database in my system the application is working fine. That db address i used in the code is given by the person who asks me to develop the application.

Comment: The connection was refused, which suggestions at least three things, 1. There is a firewall issue; 2. The server is not running or running on the specified port; 3. The server is not configured to accept incoming connections on the address/port

Comment: From of you snippets, you're using local host for the server

Comment: Actually the host i am using in the code is given by the client saying i want to connect to that DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.sqlnontransientconnectionexception: java.net.connectException : error connecting to server localhost on port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32018331/java-sql-sqlnontransientconnectionexception-java-net-connectexception-error-c)

Comment: So the derby server is running on the local machine the program is been run from?

Comment: Is there any wrong with the address provided by the client?

Comment: I think he has given the address which is in his local machine. The actual server may be different.

Comment: Here is some information on 'localhost' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost. If the db server is not running on the machine you are developing on, you need to use the network name or IP address of the machine it is running on.